# BigO Calculation of Loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm reading the BigO calculation. For the following snippet, for the worst-case scenario of the inner loop, `n*(n*8)` is given, but for the outer loop, `4n` is given. If `4` is the operation count of the outer for loop (1 for assignment, 1 for comparison, and 2 for incremental), why don't we apply the same logic to the inner one? That is, `8*n` for the inner loop and `4*n` for the outer loop. Shouldn't the outcome be `32n^2`? However, the book says (albeit seeming wrong to me)

The worst case is when the array doesn't contain duplicates and is of size `n` (= `numbers.length`):

- For the outer loop, we have `4*n` operations
- For the inner loop, we have `n*(n*8)` operations
- In total, we have `4n + 8n^2` operations

```
public boolean containsDuplicates(int[] numbers) {
     for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) { // 4 operations
       for (int j=0; j<numbers.length; j++) { // 4 operations
         if (i != j && numbers[i] == numbers[j]) return true; // 4 operations
} }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Also asked at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711884/bigo-calculation-of-loops). Can you supply a reference to the text or book that you refer to?

Comment: first of all the bigO notation of both of the solutions are the same [O(4n+ 8n^2) = O(32n^2)] and about the calculation, Is all about definition of operations.. in the book perspective the first loop happens n times and cost 4 operations and the second loop happens n^2 and cost 4 operations. beside that, inside the inner loop you have another line which cost 4 operations which happens n^2 as the inner loop and if you sum it up -> 4n (outer loop) + 4n^2 (inner loop) + 4n^2 (the line inside the inner loop) = 4n + 8n^2 . the defition on if you consider the operation or not is pretty ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

Your first `for` loops n times.

Your second `for` loops n times, for each loop of your first `for`.

So here we already have a complexity of O(n*n) = O(n^2)

Then you have your `if` : The number of operations on this line is not important as it is a constant like 1 or 2. **The important part is to study the when the return statement is executed, because the return statement stops your algorithm.**

So the **best case** is when you execute that return statement as soon as possible.

The **worst case** is when you execute the return statement at the end of the algorithm when you have looped n^2 times, or worst yet : you never call the return statement.

Best case : you must have i!=j. When do you have i!=j for the first time ?: when i=0 and j = 1. So you have looped 1 time in the second `for` loop (the time when j=0). This is just 1 loop, independant of n.

Then you must have numbers[0] == numbers[1] in the best case. Let's say you have it, so you now execute the return statement.

Thus, your best case complexity (Omega) is **Omega(1)** as, what ever the size n, in the best case scenario, you return in constant time.

Now the worst case is when you never execute the `if` condition, that is i == j || numbers[i] != numbers[j].

**The worst case regarding the input is thus when all numbers[] are different.**

In this scenario, you loop `n*n*c` where c is a constant representing the number of instructions in your second `for` loop (that is: the if clause). `c` is not important as it is not related to the size of your input data.
Thus you have a worst case complexity of O(n * n * c) = **O(n^2)**.

---

**If knowing `c` is important to you** : you know that the instruction `i!=j` is always executed. So it costs 1.

Then you can see that `numbers[i]==numbers[j]` is executed 1 time or 0 time depending on the result of evaluating `i!=j`.
So in the second loop, there's always 1 case over n where `i==j` so that the comparison of numbers is not executed. When looping n times, you execute 1+1-(1/n) instruction per loop. So you could says that in the worst case you execute n * n * (1+1-(1/n)) = 2n^2-n instructions, which is still O(n^2).

---

If you want to know **the exact number of instructions executed in the worst case scenario** :

The first loop :

- 1 instruction for i = 0
- n*2 instructions to do the check and the i++

The second loop :

- 1 instruction for j = 0
- n*2 instructions to do the check and the j++

The if (see above) = 1 + 1 - (1/n)

So in the worst case scenario, you execute :

```
1 + n*2*(1 + n*2*(1 + 1 - 1/n))
= 1 + n*2 + n^2*4*(2 - 1/n)
= 1 + n*2 + n^2*8 - 4*n
= 8n^2 - 2n + 1
```